# Why did some websites get bold and italic fonts all of a sudden?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts, microsoft-edge, netflix

This font issue/situation is happening on both Chrome (v 83.0.4103.116) and Microsoft Edge (v 84.0.522.40). I am on Windows 10 and checked my font settings in the os, but didn't find anything weird/wrong. This problem is only happening in these two browsers.

I made some pictures to show what is happening.

Let's start with Chrome and Netflix:

[image]

As you can see, italic and bold.

But Microsoft Edge and Neflix are okay:

[image]

On to a school website we're using for grades. First Chrome and the website:

[image]

Now Microsoft Edge and said website:

[image]

And lastly, my Chrome and Microsoft Edge font settings respectively:

[image]

[image]

I would be more than happy to accept changes and updates, but if this isn't happening everywhere, then maybe something's up. Would love to hear what you all think. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the difference for the school website. For the others, you should analyze which fonts are actually being used. See [Chrome extensions](https://www.guidingtech.com/chrome-extensions-identify-fonts/) which might work also in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @harrymc for your answer/comment. I tried Fontface Ninja. I figured out which font was displaying. I removed it from my pc, restarted, and every website was back to normal again!